# Magento 2 -> if weight =>100 then disable shipping method

Tags: magento2, product-weight

How can I disable shipping method if product have weight is more than 100 ?

Comment: There is no such thing provide by magento by default. you need to create a custom plugin for this and you need to do it.

Comment: which shipping method you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible though you have to dig out some code to change your shipping methods via enabling and disabling them on certain conditions.

Please visit this [link](https://www.mageworx.com/blog/2017/05/setting-advanced-shipping-restrictions-in-magento-2/) or get a Magento expert to solve this out.